# Removing tags and its contents

Tags: php, dom

I'm writing a program that utilises a page's source code, however in certain instances I want to ignore parts of it. Ultimately I want to remove the tag which has id navigation and all of its contents, and then output the HTML.

Editted code:

```
<?php
$lol = new DOMDocument();
$fh = fopen("test.txt", "r");

$lol->loadHTML(fread($fh, filesize("test.txt")));
$lol->saveHTML();

 $xpath = new DOMXpath($lol);
 $nodeList = $xpath->query('//navigation');
 foreach ($nodeList as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
 }

/*
foreach($divs AS $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('id') == "navigation") {
        $lol->removeChild($div);
    }
}
*/


$out = $lol->saveHTML();

echo $out;
?>
```

From what I've read online I would have expected this to work, but doesn't.

Any suggestions appreciated.

test.txt is just a text file with source code of the page it.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yet another web crawler... Try using xPath: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php and select `//navigation` (OK, it may be overkill in this case). Also, do an `echo $lol->saveHTML();` after calling `loadHTML`, just to make sure that it actually loads it properly...

Comment: Correct on the web crawler front, its an open source search engine for a site that doesn't currently have one and it's matching the navigation and giving high priority so wanting to start it out on all put the initial page.

Comment: Updated the code after trying xPatht to no prevail.

Comment: Well, seeing as no one asked... **How does your HTML look like?**

Comment: I'm sorry for making you sweat for your answer, but you have to learn to debug your code if you want to get something decent working. First of all, are you SURE that you are loading that file properly? Why are you not using http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php ? Afterwards, see if the xPath selects what you desire by dumping the contents of $element. You should find plenty of examples on the page I provided. After you have details about the errors that you encounter, then we can try to help. Usually, PHP gives some messages if something is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the comments have got you most of the way there. It just looks like the XPath needs a little tweaking. `$xpath->query('//navigation')` will search for `<navigation>` tags, while you are looking for tags with the *id* navigation:

```php
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($lol);
 $nodeList = $xpath->query("//*[@id='navigation']");
 foreach ($nodeList as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
 }
```

XPath is pretty powerful for this sort of thing, this [W3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) is a good place to start learning some more.

(if that doesn't work I'll echo the calls to post the relevant HTML).